# scatter plot with time data

Tags: matlab, time, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot a time-series graph using the data in my csv file.

my code is like:

```
[d,s]=xlsread('CSVLog_20220620_115817.csv')
x= s(:,1);
x1 =datenum(x,'HH:MM:SS')
y= d(:,105); 
scatter(x1,y)
title('Time vs FCR_L/H')
xlabel ('Time')
ylabel ('FCR_L/H')
grid on
```

I got an error:
Error in linear_regression (line 3)
x1 =datenum(x,'HH:MM:SS')

Caused by:
Error using dtstr2dtnummx
Failed to convert from text to date number.

can someone helps?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please read [ask] and [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In general I would recommend you to learn debugging your own code, especially if it is so short. see:  [how-to-debug-small-programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Have you checked that `x` is indeed a string of the form `'HH:MM:SS'`? You can verify that by adding a breakpoint on the line `x1 = datenum...` and check the value of `x`